# Rounding a float to 1/4ths in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, math, floating-point

what's the most elegant way of rounding a float to it's closest 1/4ths in Objective C?

For example:

```
3.14 should be 3.25
2.72 should be 2.75
6.62 should be 6.50
1.99 should be 2.00
```

etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <math.h>
...

newValue = round (value * 4.0) / 4.0;
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use an [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with a rounding increment and rounding mode set.  You can then access the float value.  Obviously, this assumes Cocoa and is more than a little heavy-handed.